# Visual Studio CSPROJ not agreeing with Solution Explorer on versions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

In my C# Visual Studio project, I open the **Package Manager Console** and entered:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
```

The output it gives me is:

```
Each package is licensed to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.

Package Manager Console Host Version 6.7.0.127

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmp7BD5.tmp
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for code signing.
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for timestamping.
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder' into project 'C:\Users\myuser\repos\Data%20Platform\edi-parser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser.csproj'.
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/index.json
info : Restoring packages for C:\Users\myuser\repos\Data%20Platform\edi-parser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser.csproj...
info : Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'C:\Users\myuser\repos\Data%20Platform\edi-parser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser.csproj'.
info : PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder' version '8.0.0' added to file 'C:\Users\myuser\repos\Data%20Platform\edi-parser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser.csproj'.
info : Generating MSBuild file C:\Users\myuser\repos\Data%20Platform\edi-parser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser\obj\InterestRecoveryEdiParser.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
info : Writing assets file to disk. Path: C:\Users\myuser\repos\Data%20Platform\edi-parser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser\obj\project.assets.json
log  : Restored C:\Users\myuser\repos\Data%20Platform\edi-parser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser\InterestRecoveryEdiParser.csproj (in 107 ms).
PM>
```

In my CSPROJ XML file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Config.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

So it looks like it installed version 8.0.0 (along with 8.0.0 versions of other `Microsoft.Extensions` packages).
But then in my Solution Explorer I see:

[image]

When I expand that error it tells me:

```
Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder from 8.0.0 to 5.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 InterestRecoveryEdiParser -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 8.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (>= 8.0.0) 
 InterestRecoveryEdiParser -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (>= 5.0.0)
```

What is going on here? It's as if half of my project is trying to use 8.0.0 and the other half is using 5.0.0.

When I try to run my project it tells me there are build errors, and then references this same error. How can I remove the 5.0.0 dependency and replace it with the 8.0.0 version?

Comment: The build is detecting errors and then Restoring packages.  Your csproj has "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0".  I would perform a clean build to remove all the intermediate obj files.  You can instead delete the entire bin folder which will force everything to get rebuilt.

Comment: Remove manually the 5.0.0 version from your project under visual studio. Also check to see if version 5.0.0 is available to your target framework (which seems to be .NET 6)

Comment: Thanks @Loudenvier but how could I do that (remove the 5.0.0 version from my project)?

Comment: Try to click with the right mouse button over the entry in the Solution Explorer and deleting it. Maybe selecting it and hitting DEL will do the trick. Then Close and Reopen VS, and perform a CLEAN then REBUILD ALL... I know, seems like voodoo, but sometimes a little magic is all we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try right-clicking on the project in Solution Explorer and clicking on Manager NuGet Package to open the NuGet Package Manager
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIa4A.png)

Find the older version of the Nuget package and update it to the version you need.